# How can I keep the header's text from passing over another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I've been building up this table that is like a "sandwich", despite its bareness it was hard to make and "works", however, it has a problem that I can't solve, the `word-wrap: break-word;` doesn't work in it, so my table keeps passing over another and doesn't break it as a normal table with `word-wrap: break-word;` would do. What can I do?

**How it should be:**

[image: original]

**How it is currently:**
[image: F'ing me]

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: the `word-wrap: break-word;` is on the bottom, and there is a `div` inside each `th`.

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'agroverdanab';
  src: url('./fonts/agroverdanab.eot');
  src: local('agroverdanab'), url('./fonts/agroverdanab.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-family: 'agroverdana';
  src: url('./fonts/agroverdana.eot');
  src: local('agroverdana'), url('./fonts/agroverdana.ttf') format('truetype');
}
body {
  float: center;
  border: 1px solid #9BC2E6;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 99.6%;
  height: 99.3%;
  font-family: 'agroverdana';
  font-size: 56%;
  margin: 3px;
  /*Inicio Customização Scroll*/
  scrollbar-arrow-color: #000000;
  scrollbar-3dlight-color: #0000ff;
  scrollbar-highlight-color: #DDEBF7;
  scrollbar-face-color: #9fc7e8;
  scrollbar-shadow-color: #DDEBF7;
  scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #FFFF00;
  scrollbar-track-color: #DDEBF7;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 15px;
  height: 7px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  background-color: #DDEBF7;
  width: 15px;
  height: 17px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
  background-color: #DDEBF7;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #9fc7e8;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
  width: 3px;
  background-color: #9fc7e8;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment {
  background-image: url(https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-KQfCHJwQRHQ/UtceeoSe3SI/AAAAAAAACLg/KngWcfzAPSs/s1600/setabaixo.png);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement {
  background-image: url(https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-dgdE4h4PFxM/Utceh2Sh30I/AAAAAAAACLo/_CUrC-yGxrQ/s1600/setacima.png);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: #87c2f2;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
  background-color: #77bbf2;
}
/* Fim Customização Scroll*/

.scrollingtable {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 98%;
  min-height: 95%;
  font-family: 'agroverdana';
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 0 0 100px 0;
  text-align: left;
}
.scrollingtable * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.scrollingtable > div {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.scrollingtable > div:before {
  top: 0;
  background: #9BC2E6;
}
.scrollingtable > div:before,
.scrollingtable > div > div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
.scrollingtable > div > div {
  min-height: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.scrollingtable > div > div:after {
  background: white;
}
/*match page background color*/

.scrollingtable > div > div > table {
  width: 100.085%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-right: 1px;
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > caption {
  font-size: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > * > tr > * {
  padding: 0;
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2F5496
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 6px 0 6px;
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr >:first-child:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid #9BC2E6;
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div[label]:before,
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div > div:first-child,
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * +:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: black;
}
/* aqui cor do texto */

.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div[label]:before,
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div[label]:after {
  content: attr(label);
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * +:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  min-height: 20px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
}
.scrollingtable .scrollbarhead {
  float: right;
}
.scrollingtable .scrollbarhead:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 110px;
  top: 1px;
  background: #9BC2E6;
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr:after {
  content: "";
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  top: -1px;
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr {
  background: white;
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr > * {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  padding: 0 6px 0 6px;
  height: 20px;
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody:last-of-type > tr:last-child > * {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #DDEBF7;
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr > * + * {
  border-left: 2px solid white;
}
.scrollingtable > div:before {
  top: 0;
  background:
  /*#b4d3ed*/
  #9fc7e8
  /*#9BC2E6*/
  ;
}
.footerButton {
  width: 70px;
  height: 25px;
  color: #2F5496;
  font-family: 'agroverdana';
  background-color: #D0E5F5;
  border: 1px solid #79B7E7;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.HeaderButton {
  width: 25.2px;
  height: 25.2px;
  font-family: 'agroverdana';
  border: 1px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
.footerButton:hover {
  border-width: 2px;
}
.HeaderButton:hover {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #79B7E7;
}
.footerButton:last-child {
  margin: 8px 15px 1px 0
}
.thead_prop,
.tbody_prop {
  font-family: 'agroverdana';
  font-size: 12px;
}
#content {
  left: 1px;
  border-top: solid 1px #9BC2E6;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #9BC2E6;
  flex: 1;
}
#navbar {
  padding: 3px 4px 4px 2px
}
#navbutton {
  float: right;
}
#vpad-pesq {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #9BC2E6;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  height: 1.1em;
  background-color: white;
}
#searching {
  margin-left: 2px;
  height: 1.6em;
  border: 1px solid #79B7E7;
}
#msgbar {
  border-top: solid 1px #9BC2E6;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #9BC2E6;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #F0F8FA;
}
/*#dae9f6*/

#footer {
  text-align: right;
  border-top: solid 1px #9BC2E6;
  border-top: 0;
  max-height: 50px;
}
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
tr,th,td,div {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<style>.scrollingtable > div > div > table {margin-right: 17px;}</style>
<![endif]-->
<html>

<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
  <title>Central de Controle da Engenharia</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./estilo_2.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <header style="padding: 0;text-align:center; font-family:'agroverdana';font-size:14px;font-weight: bolder; color:#2F5496;">Central de Controle da Engenharia
    <span style="text-align:right;font-family:agroverdana;color:#9fc7e8;font-size:9px;float:right;">wpadco03.r | 1.2-10</span>
  </header>

  <section id="content">
    <header id="navbar">

      <input type="text" id="vpad-pesq" />

      <select name="Filtro" id="searching">
        <option>Código</option>
        <option>Nome</option>
      </select>

      <div id="navbutton">
        <button class="HeaderButton" style="background-image: url('/sistema/imagens/arrow-first.png');" title="Primeiros"></button>
        <button class="HeaderButton" style="background-image: url('/sistema/imagens/arrow-prev.png');" title="Anteriores"></button>
        <button class="HeaderButton" style="background-image: url('/sistema/imagens/arrow-next.png');" title="Próximos"></button>
        <button class="HeaderButton" style="background-image: url('/sistema/imagens/arrow-last.png');" title="Ultimos"></button>
      </div>

    </header>
  </section>


  <div class="scrollingtable">
    <div>
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="thead_prop">
                <div label="Código Valor3 Valor3 Valor3 Valor3 Código"></div>
              </th>
              <th class="thead_prop">
                <div label="Descrição Valor3 Valor3"></div>
              </th>
              <th class="thead_prop">
                <div label="Valor1 Valor3 Valor3"></div>
              </th>
              <th class="thead_prop">
                <div label="Valor2 Valor3 Valor3"></div>
              </th>
              <th class="thead_prop">
                <div label="Valor3 Valor3 Valor3"></div>
              </th>
              <th class="thead_prop">
                <div label="Valor4 Valor3 Valor3"></div>
              </th>
              <th class="thead_prop">
                <div label="Valor5 Valor3 Valor3"></div>
              </th>
              <th class="thead_prop">
                <div label="Valor6 Valor3 Valor3"></div>
              </th>
              <th class="thead_prop">
                <div label="Valor7 Valor3 Valor3"></div>
              </th>
              <th class="thead_prop">
                <div label="Valor8 Valor3 Valor3"></div>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>001</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>002</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>003</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>004</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>005</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>006</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>007</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>008</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>009</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>010</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>011</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>012</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>013</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>014</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>015</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>016</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>017</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>018</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>019</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>020</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>021</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>022</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>023</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>024</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>025</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>026</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>027</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>028</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>029</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>030</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>031</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>032</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>033</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>034</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>035</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>036</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>037</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>038</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>039</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbody_prop">
              <td>040</td>
              <td>coxa c/sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
              <td>1.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>5.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
              <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <section id="msgbar"></section>
    <footer id="footer">
      <button class="footerButton" title="Salvar Dados">Salvar</button>
      <button class="footerButton" title="Alterar Registro">Alterar</button>
      <button class="footerButton" title="Excluir Registro">Excluir</button>
      <button class="footerButton" title="Voltar Página">Voltar</button>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What about `overflow:hidden`?

Comment: `word-break: break-all`

Comment: @Rvervuurt yeah, but as I pointed out on the "How it should be", I don't want to hide it but expand it down

Comment: @Mr_Green Sorry for asking, but where should I put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem ouccures through the *:before* and *:after* element with the css stye *position*

The div has the attribute labels which are being displayed in these pseudo elements.

Removing those elements and add the labels directily inside the div

```
<div>label1 label2 label3....</div>
```

additionally removing  the *white-space: nowrap* in

```
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2F5496;
}
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `white-space: nowrap` and `position: absolute` from `.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div[label]:before,
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div > div:first-child,
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * +:before`.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/0do35f4w/)

Seriously, take some time to add classes to those elements.

If you want them to align top, add:

```
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > * > tr > * {
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;  /* added */
}
```

Comment: But wait, it kinda screwed up the scrolling :/

Comment: @Calne can you explain clearly? for me the scrolling is working fine here. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/0do35f4w/1/)

Comment: but the fixed header is not fixed anymore, which happens to be the most important thing for the table :/